# A donde se envia el input de los formularios?

Tags: html, formularios, input

Acabo de hacer un formulario en html, pero quiero saber una cosa. Resulta que se escribe  y entre las comillas se pone el link a donde se ira todo el input del formulario
Pero yo no se como ver esos resultados que marqué y envié
O sea, donde se va? Como puedo verlo? En otras palabras, si envio el formulario a una persona para que lo complete, como puedo ver los datos que envió?

Ya he probado con poner un link de google en el  pero no resulto.
Tambien he probado mandar los datos a un cuadro de texto dentro del formulario y no funciono. Y ya he probado mandarlo a otro documento html y tampoco me funciono.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y realizar el [tour]. Por favor intenta ser más específico con tu pregunta. Por otro lado, existe algo llamado *consola del navegador* en la cual podrás consultar las solicitudes y datos que son enviados por tu navegador. Saludos

Comment: Coloca el codigo que hiciste y en que lenguaje estas trabajando. .Net, java, php?

Answer (score 0):

A ver... Primero debería explicarte como funciona una petición.
Cuando vos llenás datos de un formulario, estás trabajando en tu computadora (en tu casa, ponele). Cuando enviás los datos, los enviás a través de un protocolo que se llama http (hay otros, como https, http2, etc... pero vamos con ese).

¿Que quiere decir? Que tu navegador "empaqueta" las cosas que vos escribiste, las mete en un mensaje de http y lo envía a otro lado.
Por ende: todo funciona de esta manera:

Cliente (tu computadora) ----> HTTP ---> Servidor (Computadora que está en otro lado)

Por lo tanto: si vos querés guardar los datos de un formulario y que los vea otra persona en otra computadora (en otro cliente), deberías armar un script en el servidor que guarde esos datos (o en una base de datos, o en un archivo, o algo así), para que la otra persona (en otro lugar) pueda accederlos.
En dibujitos, sería así:

Cliente A (tu computadora) ----> HTTP ---> Servidor

Cliente B (el que quiere ver lo que llenaste) ----> Pide una url ---> HTTP ----> Servidor ---> HTTP (devuelve los datos que llenaste) ---> Cliente (ve los datos que llenaste).

Por ende, no es tan fácil como escribir un formulario en html. Es difícil que me entiendas, quizás, pero te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre esto:

- Arquitectura cliente/servidor (https://definicion.de/cliente-servidor/)
- Como funciona http ([introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6jKkd3buI0o))
- Que es un webserver
- Que es una base de datos

Por último, cuando tengas claros esos conceptos, bastaría con agregar la url del archivo alojado en el servidor que va a guardar tus datos en el action del formulario.

```
<form action="https://miservidor.com/guardar_archivo.php" method="POST">
  ....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

esos datos de los formularios son enviados a un servidor para ser procesados y hacer peticiones con ellos, si quieres enviar datos de un formulario a otro lo haces mediante php, creas un archivo php en donde reciba los datos mediante post o get y de ahi los envias a otra parte o haces lo que sea con ellos, ejemplo:

```
<form action="recibir.php" method="post">
<submit>Enviar</submit>


<?Php
 datos = $_POST["name_del_input_del_formulario"];
 echo $datos //imprimiendo los datos
 ?>
```

y mil cosas mas puedes hacer